# How can I add Rack Middleware to the test environment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rack, middleware, livereload

### Situation

I am currently testing a Rails app using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). In addition, I was using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) with its extension [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) to automatically reload my browser as soon as relevant source files changed.

As the `save_and_open_page` method from Capybara did not display stylesheets correctly, I applied [this solution](https://coderwall.com/p/jsutlq/capybara-s-save_and_open_page-with-css-and-js) to the problem, in which a temporary view-dump `capybara.html` gets placed in the `/public/` folder to ensure the accessibility of assets.

Now, as LiveReload has worked like a charm in development, I would like to use it during feature-tests to automatically reload `/public/capybara.html` instead of opening it over and over myself.

### Problem

For some reason I can only insert the Rack Middleware, which is responsible for reloading the page, into the middleware-stack within the developent-environment, but not within the test-environment. I use the following code for insertion:

**/config/environments/development.rb**

```ruby
Rails.application.configure do

  config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::LiveReload

end
```

When using the same method in `/config/environments/test.rb`, the following error occurs

```
myApp/config/environments/test.rb:44:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Rack::LiveReload (NameError)
```

As I am still rather new to Rails, I don't really know where to start here. As far as I know, trying to require the file manually wouldn't really be *The Rails Way<sup>TM</sup>* .
So, how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gemfile you are probably only loading the rack-livereload gem in the development group -- for this to work you would need to be loading it in the development and test groups.  That being said, you really want your test environment to mimic production as closely as possible, so running rack-livereload in the test environment would usually be a bad idea.

Comment: Good point. I will definitely consider it when I'm done testing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should include the `Rack::LiveReload` in your test environment inside `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rack-livereload"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution.